# inheritance in knockoutJS components within magento 2's knockout framework

Tags: magento2, knockoutjs, requirejs

I have been experimenting with a custom module with KnockoutJs on the frontend in M2.

I've created two components: a ProductPackage and a ProductPackagePopop. Functionally, the ProductPackage triggers a modal that renders some details about the package's children.

These two components share quite the same logic which I would like to share between the components. For example, both have a function `initTranslation` which retrieves the right translations for this store id.

Since I am new to the magento2 Knockout implementation, is there some way to create a base component from which my two components inherit the shared logic? Or a trait like in PHP. I've looked at mixins, but it seems to me it's more fit to extend external is.

```
define(['uiComponent'], function (Component) {

    return Component.extend({
        store_id: 0,

        initialize: function (config) {
            this.store_id = config.store_id;
            this.initTranslations(config.productPackage);
        },
        initTranslations: function (productPackage) {
          //some logic here
        },
        children: function(){
         // retrieves children
        }


    });
});
```

I've found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16569810/knockout-viewmodel-base-class-javascript-inheritance , but I find it hard to fit that in the M2 Knockout/RequireJs wrapper.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do this, you need to create basically 3 components.

1. Your base component. I am calling this `BasePackage`.
2. `ProductPackage` component
3. `ProductPackagePopop` component.

Now make `ProductPackage` and `ProductPackagePopop` extend from your base component `BasePackage`.

So inaction, if your module is `My_Example`. Then your components should somewhat look like below:

#### Your base component

File: `app/code/My/Example/view/frontend/web/js/base-package.js`

```
define(['uiComponent'], function (Component) {

return Component.extend({
    // this is your common method
    initTranslations: function (productPackage) {
      //some logic here
    },
    
    // put your common methods here in this base component
});
```

#### Your `ProductPackage` component

File: `app/code/My/Example/view/frontend/web/js/product-package.js`

```
define(['My_Example/js/base-package'], function (BasePackageComponent) {

return BasePackageComponent.extend({
    initialize: function (config) {
        this.store_id = config.store_id;
        this.initTranslations(config.productPackage);
    },
});
```

Here this component now extends from the `BasePackage` component. Due to this `this.initTranslations()` will be referred from the `BasePackage` component unless you define the same method inside your children's component such as this.

If in case, you need to define the same method inside this component, then calling `this._super()` will be invoking the parent method.

#### Your `ProductPackagePopop` component.

In a similar line, this component will look like the above.

File: `app/code/My/Example/view/frontend/web/js/product-package-popop.js`

```
define(['My_Example/js/base-package'], function (BasePackageComponent) {

return BasePackageComponent.extend({
    initialize: function (config) {
        this.store_id = config.store_id;
        this.initTranslations(config.productPackage);
    },
});
```

I hope you get the idea.

Comment: Nice! Thank you, i was experimenting with mixins, which worked, but it seemed like not the right tool for the job. This is exactly what i meant. Thanks!